# Cant open localhost:8080 for spring

Tags: spring

I am learning spring by following a youtube video on making a Coronavirus tracker.
I am at the point where I want to display my data in a browser but I load localhost:8080 it give me this error,
[image]

I am sharing my code here too,

this is my Controller,
[image]

My html file looks like this,
[image]

Only way I can load my app in browser is through this url;

```
http://localhost:63342/Coronavirus-tracker/templates/home.html?_ijt=q1fpdtnsc5urak74tso52gvu93&_ij_reload=RELOAD_ON_SAVE
```

why cant I load localhost:8080?

And if I use above mentioned url to load my app in brower, I just get black page with no data?
Am I missing something?

Comment: does your tomcat runs on 63342 (weird)? when your app starts you should see the port on the intellij console log

Comment: @tim.a I see this in my terminal "LiveReload server is running on port 35729". but I have to use localhost:63342 to load it.

Comment: I am not really familiar with live reload server but I believe you can close it by putting `spring.devtools.livereload.enabled=false` on your aplication.properties, if that's the problem